# Attempted Vandalism by Anonymous User

Tags: support, reviewing

There have been ~9 attempted vandalisms (see the [review history](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/history) if you really want to see them all) of the same kind over the last 23 hours by an anonymous user, presumably the same IP address. Is there any way we can deal with this other than just rejecting the edits? Perhaps if they are all from the same IP address, could that address be banned?

Sample suggested edit: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/8843

Comment: What I want to know is how they do it without being a member?  Do they have a script that allows them to suggest edits as if they were a member?

Comment: @user2509848 Under this question, I see "share edit close delete flag". When you are not a member, this is what you see: http://i.stack.imgur.com/OCUCY.png (just open a new browser or an incognito window)

Comment: I see. I had never noticed that before.

Comment: I posted a comment in the question yesterday. Lets copy&paste it here:
 
Someone (probably a bot) is insisting in trying to edit the answers to add spam, it is not trying to do to random questions, it insists in this one. Someone knows the reason for this? Have this appeared high for some particular google search terms?

Comment: It looks like the 'anonymous' user has changed their display name to `an anonymous user` to make it seem like they are not logged in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First and foremost I'd like to sent a great big ***ATABOY*** to our reviewers. Unanimous rejection of all of those implies the absence of robo-reviewing. Yeah for us!

Moderators have no more direct handle on that kind of thing than do ordinary users, but I will bring it to the attention of the team. And thanks for the heads-up.