# How much information can 10k+ users share?

Tags: discussion, support, moderation

Upon reaching 10k reputation, users have access to the [moderator tools](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tools), which contains information and stats on:

- Deleted posts and votes to delete
- Closed posts and pending votes to close and reopen
- Migrated posts
- Protected posts
- New answers to old questions
- Suggested edits
- Low reputation feedback (what happens when users with less than 100 votes cast an upvote/downvote)
- The full review history of all users

Additionally, at 25k, users gain access to the [site analytics](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/site-analytics). This contains less actionable information as the moderator tools, but is still "hidden" behind a reputation barrier

From time to time, lower reputation users will ask (especially in chat) questions that can be answered with the moderation tools ([example](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/57454982#57454982)), or higher rep users will notice something that they'd like to share with other users. However, clearly this information is not intended for all (only 49 users currently have access to the site analytics), due to the reputation requirement. Additionally, the [diamond moderator version](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289209/which-data-from-the-moderator-analytics-can-i-share) (apparently) has a disclaimer warning mods not to share the data.

So my question is, how much of the data shown by these high-rep tools can I and should I share?

Comment: What was the site analytics threshold before we graduated? I seem to recall that I used to have access to them, but haven't made it past the 25k mark since we graduated. Not that I ever really looked at them, but still.

Comment: @Giuseppe [5000 rep](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) to see site analytics when a site is in beta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### When it is appropriate to do so

I think, while being slightly vague, this is an appropriate response. A good way to determine this would be to ask yourself:

- Is the information relevant and beneficial to any on-going conversation or discussion?
- Does it or could it affect how users react/believe/interpret other data or information?
- Would other users find the information useful?
- Does it unnecessarily highlight actions by other users not part of the discussion, or does it unnecessarily place other users in a negative light?

If the answers to these questions are "Yes", "Yes", "Yes" and "No", then the information should be alright to share. Again, once you have access to this information, Stack Exchange believes that you have demonstrated a reasonable amount of trustworthy behaviour, and that you can be trusted to appropriately use it.

If you aren't sure whether it is or isn't appropriate, err on the side of caution, and don't share. If others believe that it is, they'll share it instead, and it avoids people jumping the gun because they're unsure.

Additionally, for the diamond moderators, you have been trusted with a *significant* amount of information, as well as a large amount of trust by both the community and the network. Here, I believe the moderators are more than capable of making a sensible decision about whether or not to share a piece of information.

One slight edge case is when users want to begin a discussion based on information they saw in the moderator tools. For example, noticing an [odd trend in activity](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16272/66833), discussing our [protected questions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/22108/66833) or addressing [inappropriate behaviour in the review queues](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1079/66833). These are appropriate examples of where moderation data is shared, because the answers to the other three bullet points above are "Yes", "Yes" and "No", and the data was used to start a beneficial discussion.